# IE 9 compability mode with ul against a float:left

Tags: compatibility, internet-explorer-9

An ul list against a float:left is giving me serious headache in IE 9. It worked fine in IE 7 and IE 8, and now it doesn't. I've tried to change the doc type to no avail. If I leave the doctype out of it, it works fine..... but that's not the way to go.

The following example will put the bulletpoints over the yellow area in IE 9. Any pointers at all?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color:grey;
}
.somewrapper{
width:500px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
}
.imagewrapper{
float:left;
width:180px;
height:140px;
margin-right:30px;
background-color:yellow;
}
ul{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:25px;
}

ul li{
list-style:disc outside none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="somewrapper">
        <div class="imagewrapper">

        </div>
        <div class="teste">
            <h2>asdklfjaøskljf</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>aøsklfjaøs jasas fasfklf aaasfasasfa sfasfsdfasfas fasf asfasfasfasfasf asf as fasføsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>asdfasfasfasdfasf</h2>
            <p>asdfasfasfaskjf aklsjf asjklf askljf </p>
            <ul>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
                <li>aøsklfjaøsjklfaøsjklf</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>asdfasfasfasdfasf</h2>
            <p>asdfasfasfaskjf aklsjf asjklf askljf </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Downloading IE9 right now... It's going incredibly slow.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while as well. A whole lot of installing to do... But it looks quite good - apart from this...:)

Comment: Quit the download. It was taking more than an hour. Sorry...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, not right now. It's on my work machine, and I've only got XP back home. Can provide it in 12 hours....:)

Comment: Lol, I could provide an answer then in at least 20 ;)

Comment: [As promised:)](http://i.imgur.com/ghoCQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding overflow:hidden, and then some padding tweaking I solved the most worst part. It wont flow completely around, but it will work good enough!

So overflow:hidden is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer is to use `list-style-position: inside;`

Comment: +1 because overflow:hidden made the bullet points invisible in Chrome, but this solution worked for Chrome, FF, and IE11.